# For responsive is it require component level testing?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries

In my responsive layout with reactjs, according to the width i made the template wrapper `div` became `display:none`. it works. But I got another recommendation to check in ts file and return the value as null. is it really required apart from `media-query`?

component.ts:

```
import React from "react";
import { useWindowDimensions } from "./../hooks/useWindowDimensions";

const SideBar = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        return null; //is it really required, when used in media query in css?
    }
    return <div className="sidebar">Right menu</div>
}

export default SideBar;
```

css :

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) and (max-width:768px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

is both are required? if so why we need them both?

Answer (score 0):

Using the css approach causes your code  to be responsive, whereas the first approach causes your code to only check the size of the window at lifecycles. Having said, you can achieve the same  result by calling a function inside a useEffect hook with window being passed as the second argument. Now for your question, no , there is absolutely no need to have them both. They are overlapping in getting the same result. So it's better to only have one. ( my preference is  the css approach )